# new() for Julia Arrays

Tags: julia

I struggle with writing a proper constructor for my struct `PERK`. What gives my trouble is the usage of `new()` with my member arrays. The code looks like this:

```
abstract type PERKTYPE end

struct PERK <: PERKTYPE
    NumStages::Int

    ACoeffs::Array{BigFloat}
    c::Array{BigFloat}
  
    function PERK()

      ACoeffsFile = open("some/existing/file.txt", "r")
      NumStages = countlines(ACoeffsFile)
      close(ACoeffsFile)
      #println(NumStages)

      ACoeffs = Array{BigFloat}(undef, NumStages, 2)
      
      # Fille ACoeffs with data from file, omitted here

      c = Array{BigFloat}(undef, NumStages)
      for i in 1:NumStages
        c[i] = (i-1)/(2*(NumStages-1))
      end

      new(NumStages) # Fine
      new(ACoeffs, c) # Not working if un-commented

    end # PERK()
  end # struct PERK
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Matrix{BigFloat} to an object of type Int64
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::LLVM.GenericValue) where T<:Signed at ~/.julia/packages/LLVM/gE6U9/src/execution.jl:27
  convert(::Type{T}, ::LLVM.ConstantInt) where T<:Signed at ~/.julia/packages/LLVM/gE6U9/src/core/value/constant.jl:89
  convert(::Type{T}, ::Ptr) where T<:Integer at ~/Software/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/base/pointer.jl:23
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] PERK()
   @ Trixi ~/.../methods_PERK.jl:26
```

What is going on here? Of course, I am not interested in any conversion of my arrays at all.

Comment: See the same post on Julia Discourse with [solution](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/new-function-for-arrays/81766/2?u=dandoe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can be wrong here, but `new()` creates an PERK struct. Meaning a struct with three arguments. If you call `new()` with just a `NumStages` it is fine, because it is the first argument of the struct. However

```
new(ACoeffs, c)
```

tries to feed an array `ACoeffs` into `NumStages` which yields the error you see.
You can overcome this using

```
new(NumStages, ACoeffs, c)
```

Hope this helps a little.